# Implementing random number probabilities in an existing R data frame, probabilities used are contingent upon another column

Tags: r, dataframe, random, conditional-compilation

I'm using Walker's alias method to adjust random rounded data, that is base 3. I have already assigned the column value to the each value of 3 in the dataframe, the `AliasColumn'. The values in the`AliasColumn`are integers in the range`1`through`5`. [I've used the Alias Method from here](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/). The dataframe looks like this (it has 64 rows):

```
 Industry     AliasColumn
 1            5
 2            5
 3            4
 4            2
 5            3
 6            1
 7            2
 8            2
 9            3
10            5
11            4
12            4
13            4
14            2
15            2
16            1
17            4
18            3
19            5
20            5
```

Based on the `AliasColumn` value, I need to toss a loaded coin to create the "real" business count (`NumBusinesses`), which is between 1 and 5. The loaded coin table is:

```
 AliasColumn      1      2      3     4       5
 "Heads prob"    8/12   11/12   1    10/12    5/12
 "Alias prob"    4/12    1/12   -     2/12    7/12
 Alias value      2      3      -     3       1
```

For example, if the `AliasColumn` value is 1, then 8/12 of the time the `NumBusinesses` value will be 1 and 4/12 of the time the `NumBusinesses` value will be 2. For the `AliasColumn` value of 3, that is the only value that can be assigned to `NumBusinesses`.

Thus, `NumBusinesses` receives one of two values, with a probability conditional to the specific column in the `AliasColumn`. Because the `NumBusinesses` column can only take one of two values, and because these are integers, and differ depending on the value in `AliasColumn`, I was hoping to use the [sample()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/sample) function in R. I have been unable to get this to work.

I have tried (I've just noticed in my code that I have show the code for `AliasColumn` value 4 differently to that for 1 and 2, but the output didn't seem any different to when I ran it initially with `1:2` and `2:3` instead of `1,2` and `2,3`, respectively):

```
foo$NumBusinesses[AliasCol==1] <-sample(c(1,2),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(8,4))
foo$NumBusinesses[AliasCol==2] <-sample(c(2,3),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(11,1))
foo$NumBusinesses[AliasCol==3] <- 3
foo$NumBusinesses[AliasCol==4] <-sample(c(3:4),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(2,10))
foo$NumBusinesses[AliasCol==5] <-sample(c(1,5),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(7,5))
```

This seems to set the `NumBusinesses` value to be the same as that in `AliasColumn`, apart from when the `NumBusinesses` value is 5, and then the `AliasColumn` value is being set to 1.

I considered an ifelse loop, and attempted one:

```
ifelse(foo$AliasCol==1, foo$NumBusinesses<- Sample(c(1,2),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(8,4)),
                                       ifelse(foo$AliasCol==2),
                                       foo$NumBusinesses<- sample(c(2,3),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(11,1)),
                                       ifelse(foo$AliasCol==3), foo$NumBusinesses<- 3,
                                       ifelse(foo$AliasCol==4), 
                                       foo$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(3:4),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(2,10)),
                                       foo$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(1,5),1, replace=TRUE,prob=c(7,5)))
```

And I received this error (which makes me believe I am overthinking the loop):

```
 Error in ifelse(foo$AliasCol == 1, foo$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(1,  :   unused arguments (foo3$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(2, 3), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(11, 1)), ifelse(foo$AliasCol == 3), foo$NumBusinesses <- 3, ifelse(foo$AliasCol == 4), foo$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(3:4), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(2, 10)), foo$NumBusinesses <- sample(c(1, 5), 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(7, 5)))
```

How can I generate my conditional output in one step, or one set of steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have this:

```
#probabilities of not changing AliasColumn
headProb<-c(8/12,   11/12,   1 ,   10/12,    5/12)
#alias values when AliasColumn changes
aliasValues<-c(2,3,NA,3,1)
#your data.frame
df<-structure(list(Industry = 1:20, AliasColumn = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L
)), .Names = c("Industry", "AliasColumn"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Then you can try:

```
ifelse(runif(nrow(df))<=headProb[df$AliasColumn],
       df$AliasColumn,aliasValues[df$AliasColumn])
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.